# I moved a wordpress site to another folder, Links in the menu take me to the old location

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site in the root of my domain, I copied that site to a folder inside the root doing the following:
1.- Exported database of root installation using phpmyadmin
2.- Copied all contents of root domain to the folder "domain/folder"
3.- Created an empty database.
4.- Modified the "domain/folder/wp-config.php" file with the new database info
5.- Modified database paths using "update wp_posts set guid = replace(guid, 'http://domain.com/','http://domain.com/folder/');" modified in wp_posts guid, post_contents and wp_options.
Everything seems to work but when I access the items in the menu the link shows "domain.com/folder/link" but when I click it it takes me to "domain/link"

Please Help

Comment: You'd probably get better help posting this on [Wordpress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) or [WebApps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) sites. This isn't a programming related question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did u change the rewrite URL in .htaccess ??

> change  this `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`  to  `/folder name/index.php [L]`. Then try may be the problem solved.

Comment: Thanks Nith, that actually solved the problem as soon as I modified the .htaccess file with the folder name the links took me to the right path.

Answer (score 1):

change the .htaccess like /folder name/index.php. after basic installation we need to do this when the folder is changes

Answer (score 0):

Well you might not have replaced the paths in the new database properly, so the quick fix is the answer number 1 i.e. in your .htaccess add the following after `RewriteEngine On`:

```
Redirect 301 / /folder
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gexton, all paths were correctly replaced in the database as the answer below I added the path to the folder in the .htaccess file and that solved without having to redirect